# KeyError in Phoenix web framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I get the following error in the client when trying to serve a page to the client:

> (KeyError) key :id not found in: %Phtest.Jobs{"@class": "Job", "@rid":
>   "#13:0", "@type": "d", "@version": 1, description: "öoisajdf
>   sadöflkjasdfö lkj", job_status: "Open", job_type: "Developer", title:
>   "Foo"} Stacktrace
>
> ```
> (phtest) web/templates/page/index.html.eex:27: Phtest.PageView."-index.html/1-lc$^0/1-0-"/1
> (phtest) web/templates/page/index.html.eex:16: Phtest.PageView."index.html"/1
> ...
> ```

It was working earlier but now I've modified my model somewhat switching out `job.id` for `job."@rid"`. My template looks like this:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" style="">
  <%= for job <- @jobs do %>
  <li class="job-list">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <a href="/jobs/<%= job."@rid" %>">
          <span class="title"><%= job.title %></span>
          <span class="label label-success"><%= job.job_type %></span>
          <span class="label label-default"><%= job.job_status %></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 buttons" style="text-align: right">
        <!-- <form method="post" action="<%= job_path(:destroy, job.id) %>"> -->
        <a href="/jobs/<%= job."@rid" %>/edit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
          Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="/jobs/<%= job."@rid" %>?action=delete" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            Delete</a>
<!--          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Delete</button>
        -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of the stack trace shows where the error is in the template.

The template in turn is still referring to the old `job.id` which is still being evaluated despite being within HTML comment brackets. Either correct it to `job."@rid"`, remove the code entirely or comment out the EEx template code like this:

```
<!-- <form method="post" action="<%= #job_path(:destroy, job.id) %>"> -->
```